# Specific class for two wordpress posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have two wordpress posts that I want to give them the same CSS class, in my style sheet I say:

```
.postid-861 .postid-862 #masthead .site-title a.logo-image img {
display: none;
}
```

This does not work. Do I miss anything? If I say:

```
.postid-861 #masthead .site-title a.logo-image img {
    display: none;
    }
```

It will work for one post only.
Please advice

Comment: Its beacause the other post has another id i suppose. so you got postid-861 put the other post has postid-862.

Comment: Please check .postid-861 .postid-861 Both are same...However use .postid-861, .postid-86X

Comment: That was by mistake, I adjusted that. But still when I say .postid-861 .postid-862 I don't get the styles applied in the intended way.

Answer (score 1):

You can give same properties to different classes by using `,` as below use that code:

```
.postid-861 #masthead .site-title a.logo-image img , .postid-862 #masthead .site-title a.logo-image img {
   display: none;
}
```

let's say i have class `image` and `title` and i want both to have red background:

```
.image , .title {
background-color:#a30;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful.

Comment: if my answer did help you , then you can accept it as best answer. :)

Comment: I can't see best answer as an option. I will definitely do this :)

Comment: thats the way you do, there is no other option.